# Custom download link sharepoint Modern library

Tags: development, spfx-extensions, libraries, modern

I have been asked if we can create a custom download link on a SharePoint Modern library, replacing the existing one, which saves the file with a name made from file metadata.

I am assuming that this can be done via SPFX extensions but have only just begun using SPFX.

Presumably the task is to:

1. Hide the exiting links (toolbar and edit menu).
2. Create the new functionality.

Can anyone comment on if/how this might work?

Answer (score 0):

You could build the ListView command by SPFX and use the custom code to hide the existing download link in the modern document library.

More references:

[Build your first ListView Command Set extension.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)

[Use an SPFx Application Customizer to add JavaScript (e.g. header) to every page in a site](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html)

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

Comment: Thanks Amy
I've managed to create the HelloWord extension.

Is it possible to override the exisitng 
data-automationid="downloadCommand"
or do I need to replace the existing items?

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to override the existing download command. you could create a new download command.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback
Those references are great. 
What the best way to create the new functionality?

Comment: You could use SPFx solution to create the listview command and develop the custom code for the download function.